# jQuery Waypoint 2.x Infinite Scroll plugin: how to fade-in new appended elements?

Tags: jquery, fadein, infinite-scroll, jquery-waypoints

The old jQuery Waypoint 2.x documentation is gone so I have no clue if this is a common item

In short, I'm using the Waypoint 2.x Infinite Scroll plugin and I'd like to fade-in the new appended items instead of firing them immediately

My code is extremely simple (and it works):

```
$( ".infinite-container" ).waypoint( "infinite" );
```

Please, any help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( ".infinite-item" ).fadeIn();
$( ".infinite-container" ).waypoint( "infinite", {
    onAfterPageLoad: function() {
        $( ".infinite-item").fadeIn();
    }
});
```